# Heroku Git error, please try again shortly

Tags: heroku

I get this error when deploying my Heroku application from the CLI. It always worked fine, even today a moment ago. Now I'm getting this:

```
$ git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 46, done.
Counting objects: 100% (46/46), done.  
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 4.62 KiB | 788.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 31 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0       
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: !       Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
remote: !       See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status.
remote: !       If the problem persists, please open a ticket
remote: !       on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new
remote: !       and provide the Request ID dee02a42-c0d2-4740-b9f3-cbfb58c7d95f
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/vaquita-escolar.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/vaquita-escolar.git'
```

Advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try following the advice Heroku itself printed here ("see [site]" and "try again shortly")? If the problem persisted, did you try the subsequent advice ("open a ticket on [site] and provide [request ID]")?

Comment: Hello! I am having the same problem today. I think they are having some outage problems.

Comment: @torek I have a free plan so I can't create a ticket, they directed me here.

Comment: You should mention these things in the question. It does seem like it's a temporary outage that's being persistent, though.

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary Heroku issue. It works now (today).